# Why are the quartiles in seaborn boxplot different from ploty? How can I put them to show me the same result?

Tags: python, plotly, seaborn, boxplot, quartile

## Seaborn

1. Importing libraries and load data

```
import pandas as pd

import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

sns.set_theme(style="whitegrid", palette="muted") # Set2, muted, pastel, colorblind

# Load the data
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.gapminder()
df.head()
```

2. Show the boxplot and the quartiles

```
sns.boxplot(
    data=df[df.year==2007],
    x='lifeExp',
    orient="h",
);

print('q1', df[df.year==2007]['lifeExp'].quantile(.25))
print('median', df[df.year==2007]['lifeExp'].median())
print('q3', df[df.year==2007]['lifeExp'].quantile(.75))

plt.show()
```

## Plotly

1. Show the boxplot and the quartiles

```
fig_box = px.box(df[df.year==2007], x='lifeExp', orientation='h',
                 width=500, height=300)
fig_box.show()
```

## Why do the quartiles are different?

Answer (score 1):

I am not competent enough to explain the statistics to you, but it seems to be caused by the difference in the completion method between the 25% and 75% quartiles. Simply put, pandas(seaborn,numpy) and plotly have different calculation methods by default.

```
import pandas as pd
x = df[df.year==2007]['lifeExp'].values
pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(x.ravel()).describe()).transpose()
```

|  | count | mean | std | min | 25% | 50% | 75% | max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 142 | 67.0074 | 12.073 | 39.613 | 57.1602 | 71.9355 | 76.4133 | 82.603 |

**pd.Series.quantile**
[See this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.quantile.html)

> interpolation{‘linear’, ‘lower’, ‘higher’, ‘midpoint’, ‘nearest’}
> This optional parameter specifies the interpolation method to use, when the desired quantile lies between two data points i and j:

- linear: i + (j - i) * fraction, where fraction is the fractional part of the index surrounded by i and j.
- lower: i.
- higher: j.
- nearest: i or j whichever is nearest.
- midpoint: (i + j) / 2.

```
pd.Series(x.ravel()).quantile(q=0.75, interpolation='higher')
76.423 <- plotly.box.Q3

pd.Series(x.ravel()).quantile(q=0.25, interpolation='lower')
56.867 <- plotly.box.Q1
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

r-beginners has already answered your primary question, but the secondary question seems to remain un-answered:

> How can I put them to show me the same result?

[`px.box`](https://plotly.com/python/box-plots/) has three built-in options for [calculating quartiles](https://plotly.com/python/box-plots/#modifying-the-algorithm-for-computing-quartiles):

```
['linear', 'exclusive', 'inclusive']
```

If you have [pre-computed values or if you need to use a different algorithm](https://plotly.com/python/box-plots/#box-plot-with-precomputed-quartiles) than the ones provided, you can specify them for your `px.box` figure like so:

```
fig.update_traces(q1=[df['lifeExp'].quantile(.25)],
                  median=[df['lifeExp'].median()],
                  q3=[df['lifeExp'].quantile(.75)],
                  lowerfence=[df['lifeExp'].min()],
                  upperfence=[df['lifeExp'].max()],
                 )
```

#### Plot

[image]

But beware that you may experience some irregular behavior if you try to manually set only ***one*** of the above. In this case it seems that the underlying calculations for the plot may revert to the default. I'll get back to you if I find out more.

#### Complete code:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.gapminder()

df = df[df.year==2007]#.tail(8)

fig = px.box(df, x = 'lifeExp', orientation = 'h')

fig.update_traces(q1=[df['lifeExp'].quantile(.25)],
                  median=[df['lifeExp'].median()],
                  q3=[df['lifeExp'].quantile(.75)],
                  lowerfence=[df['lifeExp'].min()],
                  upperfence=[df['lifeExp'].max()],
                 )

fig.show()
```

Comment: Doing it manually it works, but it suppose to work in a normal way. I'll try use one of if (['linear', 'exclusive', 'inclusive']) and see if the result matches

Comment: @ElizioEzra I tried. They don't. But I suspect a bug. I'm currently on 5.1.0. Do let us know if you get other results on your end.